# Customizing TeamLook - Taskitem Window etc

Tags: c#, tfs, outlook

I'm trying to customize TFS a bit, since I think TFS and outlook could be connected better.

If I get this right, there are 2 options to open a TFS WorkItem: TeamLook Window or Visual Studio Addin Window.

My goal is to automatically open a window with TeamLook, since I want to create a addin for all users, not just for the developers.

I made some basic stuff, like adding a mailattachment automatically to a PBI:

```
            foreach (MailItem mailItem in sel)
            {
                int id;
                if (Helper.TryGettingTaskId(mailItem.Subject, out id))
                {
                    WorkItem wi = TfsHandler.GetWorkitems(f => f.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (wi != null)
                    {
                        if (wi.Type.Name == ITEM_TYPE_NAME_TASK)
                        {
                            if (wi.WorkItemLinks.Count == 0)
                                throw new System.Exception("Task without PBI found");
                            wi = TfsHandler.GetWorkitems(f => f.Id == wi.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId).First();
                        }
                        string fileName = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(mailItem.Subject + ".msg", (current, c) => current.Replace(c.ToString(), "_"));
                        string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);

                        mailItem.SaveAs(path, OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
                        long attCnt = wi.Attachments.Count;
                        wi.Attachments.Add(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Attachment(path, Helper.GetAttachmentComment()));

                        wi.Save();
                        if (attCnt == wi.Attachments.Count)
                            MessageBox.Show("Could not save Attachment");
                        wi.Close();
                        File.Delete(path);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Everything works fine, but now I need more interaction with the TeamLook windows.
I just referenced all TeamLook DLLs I found in the standard path (C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamSolutions\TeamLook), but doesnt seem to work.

Since I dont get any informations about this Assemblies, I'm asking myself if I'm even allowed to use them as I'd like to?

If this doesnt work at all, are there other solutions for this?

As usual, thanks for all feedback

Matthias Müller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm with TeamSolutions, and TeamLook doesn't expose an API to allow you to open work item windows. We've sent you an email to find out more information about what you're developing and if we may be able to provide the support you're looking for in a future version of TeamLook.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the fast answer. I did not get an E-Mail so far. Didnt you send it to the address specified in my profile?

Comment: We sent it to an email address that you had contacted us with a while ago. Please send us a note on [our support page](http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/contact/support.aspx) with your current email address and we will be happy to help.